# Why does window.history.back() jump back two states?

Tags: javascript, html, history.js, html5-history

I have been playing with window.history.pushState and onpopstate but it seems to me that pressing back jumps back two states, skipping one.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onpopstate for an example:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};

history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2");
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");
history.back(); // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=1, state: {"page":1}"
history.back(); // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html, state: null
history.go(2);  // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=3, state: {"page":3}
```

History.js seems to display the same behaviour. See https://github.com/browserstate/history.js in the "Working with History.js directly" section. It jumps from state 3 to state 1 in the second back().

So why does it have this behaviour or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

That is because you use `replaceState` for the third example.

`replaceState` as the name implies replaces the current state.. it does not add a new one.

So after the `history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3");` the `?page=2` one does not exist in the history...

---

Quoting the [The replaceState() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method)

> `history.replaceState()` operates exactly like `history.pushState()` except that `replaceState()` modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.